# Properties of A-Softmax Loss, how to understand the decision boundary?

Tags: machine-learning

In this paper, ["SphereFace: Deep hypersphere embedding for face recognition"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08063), at section 3.2 "Introducing Angular Margin to Softmax Loss":

It mentioned that the decision boundaries will produce an angular margin of $\frac{m-1}{m+1} \theta^1_2$ where $\theta_2^1$ is the angle between $W_1$ and $W_2$.

**My question is, how to understand this decision boundary? What are the steps in order to get this?** The paper didn't show how they get the angular margin.

Here is the background about the question:

They proposed a loss which minimize angular distance between $x$ and $W$ instead of usual softmax loss function (I have skipped some details):

$L = \sum - log(\frac{e^{f_{y_i}}}{\sum_j e^{f_j}})$ where $f_j$ is the feature vector for class $j$ and $f_{y_i}$ is the feature of target class.

As $f_j$ is computed from $W_j$ $x$ (skipped bias for simplicity), and it actually equals to $||W_j||$ $||x|| cos (\theta_j)$ where $\theta_j$ is the angle between $W_j$ and $x$.

If we normalize the weight $W$ to have length of 1, $||W||=1$, then $f_j = ||x|| cos (\theta_j)$.

Finally they modified the loss function to $L = \sum - log(\frac{e^{||x||cos(\theta_{y_i})}}{\sum_j e^{||x||cos(\theta_{j})}})$

When this loss is completely minimized (all training data are correctly classified), the decision boundary for class 1 is $cos(m\theta_1)=cos(\theta_2)$, andthe decision boundary will produce an angular margin of $\frac{m-1}{m+1} \theta^1_2$. Although they mentioned about the keyword "angular bisector", but I still cannot understand it.